# Stop Chrome from closing when I exit debugger Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug a website which is made up of HTML and Javascript files, running on http://localhost:5500/

When ever I launch the debugger from within Visual Studio Code it opens a Google Chrome window, but then if I close the debugger it closes the Chrome window that it opened.

Is there a way I can exit the debugger without the chrome window closing every time?

Comment: just wanting to get to a why? the debugger is connected to that process and i dont think it could survive w/o the debugger

Comment: lets say I edit the code, I want to see my changes while I'm not debugging. Then if I open a debug session it opens a new window just for the debugger and then closes it. I would rather just use the one window for everything if that is possible

Comment: why are you stopping the debugger - theres tools to do hot reloads